# Register custom C# assemblies in the GAC

Tags: c#, .net, dll, gacutil

I wrote some codes with C# and make dll files.
When i put my Application on another system my application needs dll files beside the .exe file.
I know that some dll files copy to GAC and the exe file doesn't need the files anymore.
I also know if dll is type of ActiveX or COM we can use regsvr32 or regAsm.
But i don't know how i can register my own dll files in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the command prompt which comes with VS.

You need to use the gacutil tool

```
gacutil /i myown.dll
```

For more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

You can refer this page for doing so programmatically:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/7d3165cf-ca3b-43cc-8f77-a46dbf38f13d/

You can otherwise use Microsoft Windows Installer for deploying your application :

http://codefornothing.wordpress.com/2007/11/27/short-msi-tutorial/

And you can find the MSI here, if need be.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=25#overview

Comment: Yes,you right,but what can i do when i want setup the application to costumer's pc?maybe he hasn't VS

Comment: can i put dll into windir\assembly?

Comment: I have added a link which gives you the code for doing so via code.

Comment: Thank you Yogandra,That's true,but if the destination system hasn't gacutil.exe , this code thrown an exception.what should i do?

Comment: you will need to create an installer in this case, I've put some pointers for that!